# express: req.body is empty on PUT request (findOneAndReplace)

Tags: node.js, angular, express, put

i have a strange behavior on my express/node/mongodb server app,
seems that only when i call a PUT request with findOneAndReplace method, this one look like empty.

In fact i have this error message for validation method:

[image]

**here the code:**

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors');

//MODEL
const Clienti = require('./model/clienti');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '10mb', extended: false}));
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '10mb'}));


//UPDATE
app.put('/api/aggiorna_cliente/:id', function(req, res, next) {
console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))   --> N.B. i have the correct body rendition here 
console.log(JSON.stringify(req.params.id))
Clienti.findOneAndReplace(
    { _id:req.params.id },
    {
        address:req.body.address,
        brand:req.body.brand,
        cap:req.body.cap,
        city:req.body.city,
        civico:req.body.civico,
        email:req.body.email,
        fiscalcode:req.body.fiscalcode,
        provincia:req.body.provincia,
        utente:req.body.utente
    }, 
    function (err, post) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json(post);
    });
});
```

**here the CLIENTI model**
            const mongoose = require('mongoose');

```
        const clientiSchema = mongoose.Schema({
            utente:{
                type: String,
                required:true
            },
            cap:{
                type: Number,
                required:true

            },
            civico:{
                type: String,
                required:true

            },
            city:{
                type: String,
                required:true

            },  
            address:{
                type: String,
                required:true
            },
            fiscalcode:{
                type:String,
                required:true
            },
            email:{
                type:String,
                required:true
            },      
            brand:{
                type:String,
                required:true
            },      
            provincia:{
                province: String,
                sigle: String
            }
        });

        const Clienti = mongoose.model('Clienti',clientiSchema);
        module.exports = Clienti
```

as you can see quite all the fields are "required", that cause the validation problem on the picture above.

But if i remove the rquired field, all the data is empty (except for id)

last the way that i use service in angular

```
    updateCustomer(customer){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.put(this.UpdateCustomer+'/'+customer._id, JSON.stringify(customer), {headers: headers})
    .map((response: Response) => response.json())
}
```

what could it be?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Press F12 in Chrome open network tab. On the send, take a look at content in put request.  Do you see anything that lends credibility to the "validation" error?

Comment: no, the content are right...
i have also do a console.log just before the "findOneAndReplace" and on the nodemon server seems fine

Comment: If content is right then it's back-end related.  Why does document.model.invalidate? I think is the question. Is this your own model object or is it coming from the DOM?

Comment: is my own model "CLIENTI" defined above and include in the main file, but it looks like empty just when the findOneAndReplace happen.

The server respond me with 500